# unable to peer probe in glusterfs : Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: openstack, glusterfs

We are implementing a 3-node openstack cloud using glusterfs for storage solution. 3 nodes : controller compute and network are peers in gluster. We need to add another compute node as a peer in gluster but it is showing the following error :

```
[root@newcompute2 ~]# gluster peer probe 192.168.10.3
peer probe: failed: Probe returned with Transport endpoint is not connected
```

where 192.168.10.3 is the IP of controller node. Logs are also showing the same error.
Please suggest what may be the reason for this and the required solution.

Answer (score 5):

This indicate that their is no port open for proper communication Node1 and Node2 host.

For that you need to fire these commands on servers

1) firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=24007-24008/tcp --permanent

2) firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=24009/tcp --permanent

3) firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service=nfs --add-service=samba --add-service=samba-client --permanent

4) firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=111/tcp --add-port=139/tcp --add-port=445/tcp --add-port=965/tcp --add-port=2049/tcp --add-port=38465-38469/tcp --add-port=631/tcp --add-port=111/udp --add-port=963/udp --add-port=49152-49251/tcp --permanent

5) firewall-cmd --reload

Then try again 
command => gluster peer probe x.y.z.n (IP)
                                                                                                    peer probe: success.

Please check and revert if any other query.

Answer (score 3):

You must be sure that glusterd service has been started on the probed node. you can use the following command to start the glusterd service:

```
sudo service glusterd start
```

or you can restart the service with the following command:

```
sudo service glusterd restart
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had this error come up when I have GlusterFS configured to use SSL and there is a problem with loading the certificates as well (expired cert, etc.)  You can check this by removing the file: /var/lib/glusterd/secure-access.  If this file does not exist, then you probably do not have SSL configured and need to look for the issue elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I know its very late but I too got stuck with this problem and somehow solved it. So for others facing this issue, **one reason could be** that once the cluster is formed new nodes can be added only from one of the trusted nodes.

The [quick start doc](http://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quick-Start-Guide/Quickstart/) very clearly says

> Note: Once this pool has been established, only trusted members may probe new servers into the pool. A new server cannot probe the pool, it must be probed from the pool.

for example:

**node-1 and node-2**: part of the trusted cluster group

**node-3**: needs to be added to this cluster

then from either node-1 or node-2 write

```
sudo gluster peer probe <node-3>
```

Comment: you are right. Seems strange, but probings from two different sides are not the same. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @rth why does it seem strange? if this was not the case, any server could inject itself into an existing cluster group.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of firewall issue.

*peer probe: failed: Probe returned with Transport endpoint is not connected*

You need to run the following command in **all of your peers**.

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Answer (score 1):

From link, https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Quick-Start-Guide/Quickstart/
below step should solve problem.

Step 4 - Configure the firewall
The gluster processes on the nodes need to be able to communicate with each other. To simplify this setup, configure the firewall on each node to accept all traffic from the other node.

## iptables -I INPUT -p all -s  -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0):

*iptables -I INPUT -p all -s 192.168.10.3 -j ACCEPT*
(accpet rom one and the second
it works on my machines  :)

it is on instruction -> http://gluster.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Install-Guide/Configure/

Comment: Do you mind reporting those instructions here, so not to use external links?

Answer (score 0):

Running below commands from worker nodes solved the issue

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=24007-24008/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score -4):

Turn off firewall on both the nodes.

systemctl status firewalld.service

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.